# How to make jqgrid scroll to top when going to next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that when the page is changed the scrollbar is still at the bottom of the grid. Is there a property in the jqgrid for it to automatically scroll back to the top of the grid.

Here are the properties for my grid:

```
options = {
        datatype: 'local',
        colModel: [],
        colNames: [],
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        forceFit: true,
        shrinkToFit: typeof(settings.shrink) != "undefined" ? false : true,
        gridview: true,
        recordpos: 'left',
        scroll: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        hoverrows: false,
        loadonce: true,
        toppager: 'pager',
        pagerpos: 'right',
        pginput: false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more reasearch I found the answer. JQGrid also has a `pagerOptions.onPaging` event which allows you to execute code when changing pages.

Here is the fix I used.

```
pagerOptions.onPaging = function () {
      window.scrollTo(0, $("#header").height());
};
```

When the page changes it scrolls the page up until the header.